# Drupal Commerce KickStart : Disable Example Shipping method

Tags: drupal, e-commerce

Please tell me how to remove the example shipping method. If i disable this module, my other shipping methods also don't work.
There is no option to disable or delete this. The only option is 'Configure Component'

Comment: You might want to ask here: http://www.drupalcommerce.org/questions as people there probably will be able to assist you a lot better.

Comment: @GergelyVarga --no one cares to answer over there.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Shipping Services page (admin/commerce/config/shipping/services/flat-rate) and delete the example shipping method(s).

Comment: There is no option of delete. The only option is 'Configure Component' -- @TheodorosPloumis

Comment: Don't you have user 1 access? If you cannot delete them go to "admin/config/workflow/rules" and disable the rule for the example shipping.